# Undefined array key when trying to get a value out of a textbox

Tags: php, html

im currently trying to get a value from a textbox but im always getting undefined array key.

```
<head>
    <!-- Links -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/vouches.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content">
          <form method="get"><input type="text" id="oderid" name="oderid" placeholder="oderid / invoiceid"></form>
          <form method="post"><input type="submit" name="button1"class="submitbtn" value="Button1" /></form>
          <?php
          if(array_key_exists('button1', $_POST)) {
              button1();
                  }
                  function button1() {
                      $id = $_GET['orderid'];
                      echo $id;
                  }
              ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

in the  part is where the stuff happens. I hope i can get some help, im really new to php

When clicking the button it should echo $id, better said the textbox input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use both `POST` and `GET`; pick one.. Like this:

```html
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" id="oderid" name="orderid" placeholder="oderid / invoiceid" />
    <input type="submit" name="button1" class="submitbtn" value="Button1" />
</form>

<?php
    if(array_key_exists('button1', $_POST)) {
        button1();
    }

    function button1() {
        $id = $_POST['orderid'];
        echo $id;
    }
?>
```

Also take care of your spelling, orderid is not the same as oderid.